# Querying relationship status changes in a year

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to query `open graph` or `fql` to find out the number of times a user changed his/her relationship status in a year?

I m able to query to find current relationship status in the [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer), but i m interested in previous ones as well. like within a time frame. is that possible?

How can i query fql or open graph to get that info?

or lets say i want to query relationship status changes in a year?

Comment: I don't believe you have access to past relationship statuses via the API. You may perhaps be able to go back through the users' feed, but you would have to fetch the entire feed and go through each item.

Comment: ok what do u mean by feed? activity log in timeline? there is no more feed i guess.

Comment: depending if the story appears in the feed, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently unable to do this and the previous answers are correct. We found a bug within FB and it is detailed here.

[Facebook Timeline - Activity Log - Graph API - FQL Query All Return Data Based Only on Current Value (Major Bug?)](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/q/13570652/1090148)

If you have any suggestions we'd love to hear them.

Comment: Would be interested to see what you've found so far. Can you email me at anthonycoombs1@gmail.com. We've been working on something for a month now and would be interesting to compare notes.